# ASP.NET Core 2.0.0 Web application on Windows IoT

Tags: asp.net-core, iot

I have a RPI running Windows 10 IoT. Using [this link](https://damsteen.nl/blog/2017/06/30/how-to-run-aspnet-core-application-on-windows-iot) I managed to get a web api running that says "Hello world", but now I'm stuck.

What I want is a web page with a few buttons that I can put some code behind to control stuff.

I have searched to find a simple button -> action example but all I found was way over the top (for my purpose) MVC examples. I just need something simple but I can't figure it out.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/razor-pages/?tabs=visual-studio You can check Razor Pages framework. There is no WebForms for ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose jQuery+ajax to excute behind code, for example :

> **Razor Page(Contact.cshtml)**

```
    <input type="button" value="Button1" id="button1" />
    <input type="button" value="Button2" id="button2" />
```

> **JavaScript Code**

```
 $(function () {
    $("#button1").click(function () {
        $.post("/Sample/Action1", function (result) {
            alert("Click Button1,Action1 Success!");
        });
    });

    $("#button2").click(function () {
        $.post("/Sample/Action2", function (result) {
            alert("Click Button2,Action2 Success!");
        });
    });
});
```

> **Behind Code(SampleController.cs)**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Action1()
    {
        //action 1 ...

        return Json(new { Success = true });
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Action2()
    {
        //action 2 ...

        return Json(new { Success = true });
    }
```

Before that, you should make sure jquery library is included in your page.